# Find the best model exponent of the observed data R

Tags: r, model-fitting

I would like to know how to fit this model/equation

```
y~x^(-p)
```

to my data to find the best value of the exponent `p`

My data are:

```
y=c(1.1178329,1.0871448,1.0897010,1.0759255,1.0535190,0.8725332)
x=c(6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

I tried the following way

```
mod <- nlsLM( sigmasG ~ x^(-p),
 start = c(p = 0.01) , 
trace = TRUE, lower=c(0.01) , upper=c(1))
```

but the outputs don't change...

```
It.    0, RSS =  0.0671647, Par. =       0.01
It.    1, RSS =  0.0671647, Par. =       0.01
```

Thank you to anyone who can help with this adjustment to find the `p`

Comment: Have you tried using log?          result <- lm(log(y) ~ x);     p <- - result$coefficients[2]

Comment: @csgroen , thanks for the tip, in your answer the value of p is given by p <-  
   -result$coefficients[2] ? With a sinal of minus in the front of result$coefficients[2] ?

Comment: Please ensure posted questions are complete and self contained.  The library statement is missing on this one.  See [mcve]

Comment: @davidclarck Yes. But thinking about it, it should actually be lm(log(y) ~ log(x)). But p would still be -result$coefficients[2]. It's like applying log to both sides so that p can become a linear coefficient. However, note that the R-squared for this model is around ~0.78

Comment: @csgroen, when making the relationship  lm(log(y) ~ log(x)), my p was:

p(log(x))= -0.1247224. This make sense ? thaks

Comment: @davidclarck it's not a perfect model. Try doing x^-p and see how far the values are from y and whether it's acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

If you try it without the upper and lower bounds then it finds a negative value for p so it is not surprising that it drives the value to the lowest possible value in the feasible region.

Also, as an aside it is not a good idea to have a starting value on the boundary of the feasible region although in this case it seems it does not matter.